Is there a way to remotely start a discord bot with another discord bot?
So I'm making a Discord bot that has 3 slash commands which are "start", "stop", and "restart" but I am stuck on /start. I've coded the part where if /start is run, it should node the other bot I have in another directory, but I am always hit with a "DiscordAPIError[20012]: You are not authorized to perform this action on this application". It does start the bot, but doesn't load the slash commands which is a problem for me since the bot I want to start has commands
Code:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permissions, MessageManager, Embed, Collection, Events } = require(`discord.js`);
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.commands = new Collection();

require('dotenv').config();

const functions = fs.readdirSync("./src/functions").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/events").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands");

(async () => {
    for (file of functions) {
        require(`./functions/${file}`)(client);
    }
    client.handleEvents(eventFiles, "./src/events");
    client.handleCommands(commandFolders, "./src/commands");
    client.login(process.env.token)
})();

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (interaction.commandName === 'start') {
        const childProcess = require('child_process');
        const path = require('path');

        const batchFilePath = "D:\\bots\\start.bat"

        const options = {
            stdio: 'ignore',
            detached: true,
            shell: true
        };

        childProcess.spawn(batchFilePath, [], options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log(stdout);
            }
        });
    }
});

Terminal:
Started refreshing application (/) commands.
DiscordAPIError[20012]: You are not authorized to perform this action on this application
    at handleErrors (D:\bots\lmao\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:727:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (D:\bots\lmao\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1128:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (D:\bots\lmao\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:959:14)
    at async _REST.request (D:\bots\lmao\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1272:22)
    at async D:\bots\lmao\src\functions\handelCommands.js:28:17 {
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'You are not authorized to perform this action on this application',
    code: 20012
  },
  code: 20012,
  status: 403,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/1295622293703360513/commands'
}
Ready!

Whenever I run the command, it opens a new terminal, then when it tries to refresh the commands of the other bot, it gives me the API error saying the action I'm trying to do is not allowed, then just turns the bot online without registering all of the commands which I need
